# Automapper - How to map to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm making Forum system, I have SubCategoryThreadsViewModel in which I'm trying to map LastComment and Date of last post for every thread. This is my code:

```
public class SubCategoryThreadsViewModel : IHaveCustomMappings
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Thread> Threads { get; set; }

    public ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel { get; set; }

    public void CreateMappings(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.CreateMap<Thread, SubCategoryThreadsViewModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.SubCategory.Title))
            .ForMember(m => m.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.SubCategory.Description))
            .ForMember(m => m.Threads, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.SubCategory.Threads))
            .ForMember(m => m.ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => new ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel()
            {
                  LastCommentBy = t.Posts.Select(a => a.Author.UserName),
                  DateOfLastPost = t.Posts.Select(a => a.CreatedOn.ToString()),
            }))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
```

The code

```
.ForMember(m => m.ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => new ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel()
        {
              LastCommentBy = t.Posts.Select(a => a.Author.UserName),
              DateOfLastPost = t.Posts.Select(a => a.CreatedOn.ToString()),
        }))
```

is working but only when property ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel is not Ienumerable as in the code above, and inside are two IEnumerable strings.

```
public class ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> LastCommentBy { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> DateOfLastPost { get; set; }
    }
```

This works, but I want ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel to be Ienumerable, and in the class properties to be string for easy foreach.

I have tried to make it IEnumerable, but with current automapper code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually map the member to an `IEnumerable<ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel>` rather than a single object.

I assume each `Post` in `t.Posts` represents one `ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel`, so a simple `Select()` should do it:

```
public IEnumerable<ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel> ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel { get; set; }

...

.ForMember(m => m.ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(t =>
    t.Posts.Select(p => new ThreadInfoSubCategoryViewModel()
    {
        LastCommentBy = p.Author.UserName,
        DateOfLastPost = p.CreatedOn.ToString()
    })
))
```

Comment: This is not working it only gives me one date and one lastComment, I want to have that information for every thread